# Reducing (Versus Delaying) Overfitting in Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, regularized, dropout

In neural nets, regularization (e.g. L2, dropout) is commonly used to reduce overfitting. For example, the plot below shows typical loss vs epoch, with and without dropout. Solid lines = Train, dashed = Validation, blue = baseline (no dropout), orange = with dropout. Plot courtesy of Tensorflow tutorials.
[image: losses with/without dropout]
Weight regularization behaves similarly.

Regularization delays the epoch at which validation loss starts to increase, but regularization apparently **does not decrease the minimum value** of validation loss (at least in my models and the tutorial from which the above plot is taken).

If we use early stopping to stop training when validation loss is minimum (to avoid overfitting) and if regularization is only delaying the minimum validation loss point (vs. decreasing the minimum validation loss value) then it seems that regularization does not result in a network with greater generalization but rather just slows down training.

How can regularization be used to reduce the minimum validation loss (to improve model generalization) as opposed to just delaying it? If regularization is only delaying minimum validation loss and not reducing it, then why use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over-generalizing from a single tutorial plot is arguably not a good idea; here is a relevant plot from the [original dropout paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/v15/srivastava14a.html):

[image]

Clearly, if the effect of dropout was to delay convergence it would not be of much use. But of course it does not work *always* (as your plot clearly suggests), hence it should not be used *by default* (which is arguably the lesson here)...

Comment: Agreed - apparently the usefulness of dropout is highly case-dependent. BTW my concern is not based on the tutorial plot, I only used that as a convenient linkable example. I have made hundreds of such plots from my models, all showing similar behavior.

Comment: @RonCohen Indeed. And you could even accept the answer (just sayin... :)