# how to reduce overfitting in neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I'm working on a sound recognition project.

I have 1500 labeled sound samples of 5 classes. (300 sound samples of a duration of 2 seconds for each classe).

I'm using an online tool to calculate the MFCC coefficients (Egde impulse) (So I can not provide the code) and then
I'm training a neural network.

The dataset is splitted :

- 80%  --> a training set which is splitted 80/20 - training/validation
- 20%  --> a test set

After 200 training cycles, the first release of my network had the (very bad) following performances :

training accuracy = 100 % / Validation accuracy = 30 %

By searching on the net and on this forum, I found method(s) to reduce overfitting :

The final performance of my last release of neural network is  the following :

training accuracy = 80 % / Validation accuracy = 60 % (after 200 training cycles)

As you can see, there is still a significant difference between training accuracy and validation accuracy..

My question is how to continue to increase my validation accuracy ?

the code of my neural network :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, Dropout, Conv1D, Flatten, Reshape, MaxPooling1D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# model architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], ), name='x_input'))
model.add(Reshape((int(X_train.shape[1] / 13), 13), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], )))
model.add(Conv1D(30, kernel_size=1, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1, padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(10, kernel_size=1, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1, padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='y_pred'))

# this controls the learning rate
opt = Adam(lr=0.005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
#opt = Adadelta(learning_rate=1.0, rho=0.95)

# train the neural network
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=50, epochs=200, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), verbose=2)
```

Thanks you,

Regards,

Lionel

Comment: A difference in training & validation performance in itself [does not signify overfitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61043558/dropout-with-densely-connected-layer/61043883#61043883).

Comment: @desertnaut, thank you for your post.Now that you've made the diagnosis, what is the solution ? Maybe I have to perform additional sound recording to increase the size of my training set  ??? What do you think ?

Comment: There is *never* an easy answer in such questions, let alone one that fits in a SO comment :)

Comment: OK, I understand !, @desertnaut

Answer (score 0):

1. Try with Stratified K fold validation [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)
2. choose different batch size {16,32,64}
3. Try with sigmoid
4. BatchNormalization()

Answer (score 0):

In general to reduce overfitting, you can do the following:

1. Add more regularization (e.g. multiple layers of dropout with higher dropout rates)
2. Reduce the number of features
3. Reduce the capacity of the network (e.g. decrease number of layers or number of hidden units)
4. Reduce the batch size