# how to reduce overfitting for a simple neural network that is trained for text processing and movie review

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to run some example Deep learning python3 code on databricks/GPU.
The code is from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification_with_hub#evaluate_the_model

I got the results :

```
 training loss: 0.0762 - training accuracy: 0.9929 
 validation_loss: 0.5734 - validation_accuracy: 0.8628
```

The example said

```
"This fairly naive approach achieves an accuracy of about 87%. With more advanced approaches, the model should get closer to 95%."
```

I want to find how to improve the accuracy.

From the results, I think it is overfitting. So, I tried to add l1 and l2 regularizer and dropout.

```
  embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
  hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[], 
                       dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
  
  tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.04, l2=0.01)  # L1 + L2 penalties
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(hub_layer)
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.3))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```

I have tried different dropout (0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7) and l1/l2 regularizers (0.01, 0.02, 0.04).

I have reduced the units in the first hidden layer from 16 to 8.
I have tried [Reducing (Versus Delaying) Overfitting in Neural Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57894274/reducing-versus-delaying-overfitting-in-neural-network) and [how to reduce overfitting in neural networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230417/how-to-reduce-overfitting-in-neural-networks)

But, no improvement.  How can I reduce the overfitting ?

thanks

Comment: How did you arrive at the various numbers for dropout and regularization? Have you tried varying these?

Comment: You could use for example Embedding layers, as state in documentation.  https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification

Comment: @N.Kiefer, please see my OP. thanks

Comment: @s3nh, please see my OP. I have used embedding layer. thanks

Comment: Searching for good parameters you will first have to find the scale. If Dropout really doesn't help (even at 0.99), you will have to up the regularization. Try 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1 and so on.